# Calling a .jar from ColdFusion and run on the client machine

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am using ColdFusion 11 and I have an eSignWeb.jar file (created in java obviously) in my class path. What this .jar does is to receive a path where a file is located on the client's computer and then analyze that file using Bouncy Castle.

But when I run it, I get the following error:

> Code: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\name\Documents\clientfile.cer (The system can not find the
>   specified path)

The error is because my .jar file tries to look for the `clientfile.cer` file on the server and not the client machine.What I need is that this .jar running on the server can search this file on the client's computer.

Important:

1. The `clientfile.cer` file can never upload to the server, so it has to be analyzed on the client side.
2. I have to use ColdFusion with java

My code in ColdFusion is simple:

```
<cfset eSign = createObject("java","eSignWeb.SignAB") />
<cfoutput>
    <!--- TEST1--->
    <cfdump var="#eSign#">
    #eSign.callsignCF()#
    <hr />
    <!--- TEST2 WITH cfscript --->
    <cfscript>
        classLoader = createObject("java","eSignWeb.SignAB");
        response = classLoader.callsignCF();
        WriteOutput("Test whith CFSCRIPT " & response); 
    </cfscript>
</cfoutput>
```

The code in my .jar file:

```
package eSignWeb;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.naming.InvalidNameException;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapName;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class SignAB {
    public String callsignCF(){

        String vCer;

        vCer = "C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\clientfile.cer"; //Path where the .cer file is located on the client side

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); // add bc as provider

        String archivoCer;
        X509Certificate certificado = null;
        Date fechaFinal;
        Date fechaInicial;
        Date fechaActual;

        //start cer
        archivoCer = vCer;

        try {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(archivoCer);

            try {

                CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                certificado = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(is);

                fechaFinal = certificado.getNotAfter();
                fechaInicial = certificado.getNotBefore();
                fechaActual = new Date();

                if(fechaActual.before(fechaInicial) && fechaActual.after(fechaFinal)){
                    return "Invalid date";                     
                }else{
                    String myVarConRFC = "2.5.4.45";

                    String dn = certificado.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
                    LdapName ldapDN = new LdapName(dn);

                    ldapDN.getRdns().forEach((index) -> {

                        if(index.getType().equals(myVarConRFC)){
                            //RFC
                            String myRFC = new String((byte[]) index.getValue()); 
                        }
                    });
                }
            } 

            catch (InvalidNameException ex) {
                return "E0: Error on cer. Code: "+ ex;
            } 

            catch(CertificateException a) { 
                    return "E1: The specified file is not a valid certificate file. Code: " +a;

            }  

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {  
            return "E2: Certificate file does not exist. Code: " +fnfe;
        } 
        // End cer

        return "Unknown error";   
    }
}
```

As you can see, the .jar runs on the server and that's why it does not find the .cer file. Any idea of ​​how to get a functionality that allows .jar to search the file on the client's machine?

If I could upload the .cer file to the server, it would be very easy, but that is forbidden. The .cer file should never leave the client's machine.

Thank you very much for any guidance in this regard!

Comment: What's the reason for analyzing the .cer file? Just wondering if the applet/web start app will ultimately do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

CF alone won't work for that type of task, because it only operates on the CF server. It can't access client files at all. Only files uploaded to the server or a location accessible to the server (which you said you can't do).

In order to access files on a client machine, you need something like a *signed* [Java Applet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) or [Web Start Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/running.html), which does run on the client. The "signed" part is important. For security reasons, applets and the like can't just access files on the client machine whenever they wish. The user must explicitly grant the Applet or Web Start application permission to do so.